# Why is attaching an event listener on react child component look the same as passing a props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class Board extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        squares: Array(9).fill(null),
      };
    }
    handleClick(i) {
        // do things
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Square
                value={this.state.squares[i]}
                onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
                />
            </div>);}

class Square extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <button
          className="square"
          onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}
        >
          {this.props.value}
        </button>
      );
    }
  }
```

If we're attaching an event listener `onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)`  Square, why do Square component able to call `this.props.onClick()`?.
The syntax look the same, are we attaching an event listener or are we passing it as props with the name onClick?

Answer (score 2):

> Why is attaching an event listener on react child component look the same as passing a props?

Because you **are** passing a prop.

The react `<button>` JSX element will create an HTML button element and attach the event listener by reading the function from the properties you pass to `<button>`.

Answer (score 0):

Is a prop actually.

The "native" `<button>` component has a prop named `onClick` that will do something like `addEventListener("click", ...)` to the element. Or simply something like `element.onclick = ...`.

The thing is that you can do whatever you want with the props you receive on your components, and those "native" components do exactly that with these kinds of props.

Comment: then how do you differentiate it from a prop or an eventlistener? is it because its not the final child or is it because its not attached to native `<button>` component?

Comment: Is not an event listener. Is a prop @Claude. You can't know what the component do is the background with the PROP. Is usually documented somewhere what each prop do.

Answer (score 0):

Because `onClick` was passed as a prop. Specifically on these lines:

```
<Square
  value={this.state.squares[i]}
  onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
/>
```

Things you pass as attributes in JSX are basically props for created object. Thus, when you call `onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}` in your Square render function, it refers to the passed prop.